# Binary Tree code - Cannot read property 'data' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
class Node {
    constructor(data, left, right) {
        this.data = data;
        this.left = left;
        this.right = right;
    }
}

class BST {
    constructor() {
      this.root = null
    }
    add(data) {
      const node = this.root
      if (node === null) {
        this.root = new Node(data)
        return
      } else {
        const searchTree = function (node) {
          if (data < node.data) {
            if (node.left === null) {
              node.left = new Node(data)
              return
            } else if (node.left !== null) {
              return searchTree(node.left)
            }
          } else if (data > node.data) {
            if (node.right === null) {
              node.right = new Node(data)
              return
            } else if (node.right !== null) {
              return searchTree(node.right)
            }
          } else {
            return null
          }
        }
        return searchTree(node)
      }
    }
    levelOrder() {
        const arr = [];
        const queue = [];
        let node = this.root;
        queue.push(node);

        while(queue.length) {
            node = queue.shift();
            arr.push(node);
            if(node.left !== null) queue.push(node.left);
            if(node.rigth !== null) queue.push(node.right);
        }
    }
}

const tree = new BST()
tree.add(1)
tree.add(2)
tree.add(3)
tree.add(4)
tree.add(5)

console.log(tree)
```

Error I keep getting

```
if (data < node.data) {
               ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined
```

I made sure to double check my code and sometimes it works other times it doesn't....

Can anyone help with this and explain thinks I'm not understanding and what I need to look into.

Comment: the problem is that node.left or node.right are **not strictly `null`** but sometimes `undefined`. So if you alter your comparisons to use weak equality for `null` which covers both `null` and `undefined` it will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the `node.left` and `node.right` are `undefined` since you're not assigning them any values when creating a new node but you're checking them for strict equality with `null` like

```
node.left !== null
```

You just simply need to change your `Node` class to this :

```
class Node {
    constructor(data) {
        this.data = data;
        this.left = null;
        this.right = null;
    }
}
```

OR

Use the Logcial NOT to check for a falsy value since `undefined` and `null` both are falsy values like

```
if( !node.left ){
 .
 .
}
```

Hope this helps !

Answer (score 1):

making my comments an answer..

The problem is that `node.left` or `node.right` are **not strictly `null`** but sometimes `undefined`. So if you alter your comparisons to use *weak equality* for `null` which covers both `null` and `undefined` it will work.

Ie change `===null` to `==null` and `!==null` to `!=null`. Else make sure you intitialise `left` and `right` to `null` always, but using *weak equality* is better.

In fact in javascript (and other languages) you can simply use `if (node)` and `if (node.left)` and so on.. since either they will `null`/`undefined` or a `Node` instance (and not zero). So even simpler test.